# handleScroll value inside React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I retrieve data from a paginated API. I would therefore like to set up a system that fetch the data of a new page as soon as the user scrolls 70% of his web page.

Do you have an elegant solution for doing this in React ?

Here is my component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.url = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character';
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      canLoad: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    this.fetchData();
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  };
  
  handleScroll(event) {
    // get scrollY value here and call fetchData() if scroll value > 70% of height page
  };

  async fetchData() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(this.url);
      const data = await res.json();
      this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, ...data.results] });
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error', err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main className="cards--section">
        { this.state.data.map(Card) }
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Thank you very much for reading me !

Answer (score 1):

apply a scroll on a container and take the reference of the container

Use the logic below to fetch the data. This will fetch data 100 px before reaching the end

container.scrollTop + container.offsetHeight > container.scrollHeight - 100

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.url = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character';
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      canLoad: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
  };
  
  handleScroll(event) {
    const container = event.currentTarget;
    if(container.scrollTop + container.offsetHeight > container.scrollHeight - 100){
this.fetchData();
}
    // get scrollY value here and call fetchData() if scroll value > 70% of height page
  };

  async fetchData() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(this.url);
      const data = await res.json();
      this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, ...data.results] });
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error', err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main className="cards--section" onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
        { this.state.data.map(Card) }
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. handleScroll function is never called and I don't understand why. 
I've try to put my onScroll logic on the first component on my tree but it doesn't works too.

Do you have a idea dude ?